# Linux prompt with current path displayed

Tags: linux, bash

What should I put in my .bashrc file to display the relative path of the current directory I am in, relative to my home directory? I also would like to show the machine name. For example, when in /home/mike/code/runner/dev, I want it to look something like this:

```
vm-esx-03:~/code/runner/dev$
```

Comment: This question is off-topic for Stack Overflow: See "What topics can I ask about here?" under https://stackoverflow.com/help/asking

Comment: @glennjackman is this really off topic? It's asking for a specific solution that involves "software tools commonly used by programmers," which is included in criteria listed as [on topic](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic). I would argue a command shell and the shell configuration would therefore be on topic in this community, as it is certainly a tool commonly used by programmers.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A shell variable known as `PS1` is responsible for displaying the default command prompt in bash. To see your current setup try `echo "$PS1"`. You can set `PS1` in your .bashrc file for a custom prompt. It sounds like you want something like this:

```
PS1="\H:\w$ "
```

Explanation:

`\H` - The hostname of the machine

`\w` - The working directory, relative to $HOME (or `~`)

You can try different combinations if you want something even more customized. For a reference, check out this blog: https://www.cyberciti.biz/tips/howto-linux-unix-bash-shell-setup-prompt.html

Comment: `PS1` need not be an environment variable; it's only used by the shell itself, so it doesn't need to be exported. Any shell that needs `PS1` is already sourcing `.bashrc`.

Comment: Thank you h0r53! That was just what I was looking for.